# Conditional Propagation of Values

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
mat<-matrix(c(272,237,266,272,225,265,117,223,262,241,210,216,252,203,170),nrow=5,ncol=3,byrow=T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  272  237  266
[2,]  272  225  265
[3,]  117  223  262
[4,]  241  210  216
[5,]  252  203  170
```

Is there a way so that if the first element in the Nth column doesn't equal to 272 that the rest of the rows be equal to that number in the Nth column? And if it is equal to 272, I will need to search skip to the row that doesn't equal 272 and then perform the same operation and let it propagate downwards?

So an example in the above data frame would turn to:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  272  237  266
[2,]  272  237  266
[3,]  117  237  266
[4,]  117  237  266
[5,]  117  237  266
```

An easy approach would be to loop through the entire thing with double for loop, but that would take forever in R. Is there any better process then looping? I understand that in most cases, there will not be a ONE line answer.

I was thinking of using na.locf() but this works for only NAs. Is there a function for carrying value forward if it meets certain conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
apply(mat, 2, function(col) 
      replace(col, seq(col) > which.max(col!=272), col[which.max(col!=272)]))
```